# Why do Lapidaria margaretae look like stones?

Tags: evolution, botany, plant-anatomy

**Previous Research**

I stumbled across a trending reddit post "[Lapidaria margaretae looks like stones](http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/2xtis9/lapidaria_margaretae_looks_like_stones/)" (as of 3rd Februrary 2015); but I could not find discussions as to reasons behind why.

**Question/s**

- Why do Lapidaria margaretae look like stones? I am interested in both the morphological/physiological reasons, as well as possible evolutionary mechanisms.
- Or perhaps I am asking the wrong question, then what should it be?

[image]

Comment: I've never seen a stone that looks like that…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Teleology is like a mistress to a biologist: he cannot live without her but he's unwilling to be seen with her in public." - J.B.S. Haldane (1892 - 1964)

I can't tell you why Lapidaria *margaretae* looks like 'stones'. But I can deduce something from the way this plant looks.

First and foremost, I can say this plant probably evolved in an arid region, possibly a desert (less than 10 inches of water per year), because it is a succulent, with a shape that comes pretty close to minimizing it's surface to volume area (decreased evaporation, decreased transpiration). Seeing as it's a dwarf and shaped as it is, I might hazard that it's windy and sandy where this plant evolved, also because of it's shape - low to the ground, sturdy, low surface area, able to resist the wind. Finally, the light color of the plant suggests a lot of bright sun (reflects sunlight more than some darker colors).

None of that is foolproof, but in this case, it turns out to be right; the plant comes from southern Namibia, and is commonly called the "Karoo rose".

This is one image of the Karoo region:

[image]

Stones come in all kinds of shapes and sizes, also influenced by water, wind and other environmental influences. That this plant looks like stones is mostly coincidental.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the significance of the quote :/

Comment: ah.. well in your defence @anongoodnurse hmm step (2) of the  scientific method (at least the Pirsigian six step flavour) requires us to dream up hypotheses!